# How to set devexpress chart in win form that For a continuous series, the minimum value is not constant and And the displayable range can be changed

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, devexpress

my axiesx in chart is date time. i wantt change min value with over time

```
                    diagram.AxisX.DateTimeScaleOptions.ScaleMode = ScaleMode.Continuous;
                    diagram.AxisX.Label.ResolveOverlappingOptions.AllowRotate = false;
                    diagram.AxisX.Label.ResolveOverlappingOptions.AllowStagger = false;
                    diagram.AxisX.WholeRange.SideMarginsValue = 0;
                    diagram.EnableAxisYScrolling = true;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Axis.VisualRange](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.XtraCharts.VisualRange) property to customize the X-Axis visible range at runtime.